# Access property of an object from jquery function within the object (JavaScript/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, object

I have the following class:

```
class Traffic {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    setEventListeners() {
        $("#btn").on('click', function() {
            $(this).text(name);
        }
    }
}
```

When clicking on the `<button id="btn"></button>`This throws the error: `name is undefined`. This makes sense to me as I would normally use `this.name` to access the object's properties. However, because I am inside jQuery, now `this` refers to the jQuery object.

How can I access the name property of the `Traffic` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just declare a new variable outside the function where `this` still points to the class instance.

```js
setEventListeners() {
    const name = this.name;
    $("#btn").on('click', function() {
        $(this).text(name);
    }
}
```